# How to auto refetch an API from another API reducers RTK query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have 2 api reducers,boardApi and taskApi.

boardApi consist of 3 query *getBoards* , *getBoardById*, & *addBoard*.

taskApi has 2 mutation, *addTask* & *deleteTask*.

how to refetch getBoardById every time task added or deleted

**boardApi**

```js
export const apiBoardSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'apiBoardSlice',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: API_URL,
    prepareHeaders: headers => headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
  }),
  tagTypes: ['Boards'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getBoards: builder.query({
      query: () => 'board',
      providesTags: ['Boards'],
    }),
    getBoardById: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `board/${id}`,
      providesTags: ['Boards'],
    }),
    addBoard: builder.mutation({
      query: payload => ({
        url: 'board',
        method: 'POST',
        body: payload,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Boards'],
    }),
  }),
})
```

**task api**

```js
export const apiTaskSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'apiTaskSlice',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: API_URL,
    prepareHeaders: headers => headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    addCard: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ listId, title, boardId }) => ({
        url: `task/${boardId}`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: { title, listId },
      }),
    }),
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Those should not be two apis. Generally, there are very few situations where you ever have two different apis in your application - this is not one of them.

Both even have the same base url and application logic - they should be multiple endpoints on the same api.

As for your question: you cannot do automatic cross-api invalidation. If you want to invalidate one endpoint from another api, it's a clear sign that both endpoints belong onto the same api.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use createApi twice.

With [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)
you can use all declared tags in all combined reducers.

So you can simply use in both task mutations:

```
invalidatesTags: ['Boards']
```